# Which dojo widget should be used for DropDown

Tags: drop-down-menu, dojo

I wish to create dynamic dropdown, meaning the value of the second dropdown changes with the change in selection on the first. I was looking through the Dojo docs and it seems there are 3 different widgets that I can use,

[dijit/form/ComboBox](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#declarative-markup-using-native-select-and-option-tags)

[dojox/form/DropDownSelect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/form/DropDownSelect.html#a-simple-dropdownselect)

[dijit.form.Select](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/Select.html#a-simple-declarative-select)

Now I am confused as to which one should i use for creating Dynamic DropDowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose anyone depending upon what extra features you want. While dijit.form.Select is your normal HTML select, combobox and filteringselect offer more features.

Follow http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/combobox-vs-filteringselect/ for a comparison between the two. You can also play with them to know how they work.

I had used FilteringSelect in my app for the same behavior as need.

Answer (score 0):

Differences between dojo dropdown :

1. Select It is simple combobox like select in HTML with no validation
   and not provide any search facility inside select options.
2. ComboBox It is pure form of combobox and name as ComboBox again it
   will not provide any default validation but it provide search
   facility within its options.
3. FilteringSelect It is an advance form of select have default
   facility of validation and search facility. And it also has property
   to take value as input tag take value in HTML.

In dojo you can also try custom validation which is provided inside dojox library. I hope it will help you.